# How display gps information on googlemap using php

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm writing an application on android, app will get information gps from mobile and send them to the server. Server will store the information into the database. Then when the user access information on the website it would take this position and display on googlemap. now, I took the gps and store information in the database. But the problem here is I do not know how to display them on a google map.

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="mysql12.000webhost.com";
$database_localhost ="a4602996_longvan";
$username_localhost ="a4602996_lv";
$password_localhost ="longvan2012";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$sqlInsert= "select Kinhdo,Vido from gps where number = (SELECT  MAX(number) FROM    gps)";
$sql=mysql_query($sqlInsert);
if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
{
  echo "<pre />";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  {
    $json[] = $row;
  }
  echo "</pre>";
}
print 'My longitude: '.$json[0]['Kinhdo']; 
print 'My latitude: '.$json[0]['Vido']; 
mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

RTM ?

Here is google maps API: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Here you have a basic example with just a map: 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-language
(read the source, replace the default values with your longitude and latitude)

And here an example with a picto (marker): 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

Good luck!